# Why is Appended content not showing up on reading from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, file-handling

Please look at this code first, then I will ask my question.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <fstream>

using std::cout; 
using std::cin; 
using std::endl;

int main() {

    std::ofstream out_file ("outfile.txt");  /* creates a outfile.txt */
           
    if (!out_file) { // checks files existence
        std::cerr << "Error bruh!" << endl;
        return (1);
    }
    
    int num = 100;
    double total = 456.78;
    std::string name = "atik";

    out_file << num << "\n"     // writing to the file
             << total << "\n"
             << name << endl;
    
    /* Reading from file, because i want to! - */

    std::ifstream in_file("outfile.txt"); // will open outfile for reading.

    char c;

    while (in_file.get(c)) {
        cout << c;
    } 

    /*
    Output (as expected) -
        100                                                                             
        456.78                                                                                          
        atik                                

    Right Now My **output.txt** file is - (as expected)                                          
        100                                                                                               
        456.78                                                                                           
        atik 
    */

    /* Appending the file that we just created - */

    std::ofstream out_file2 ("outfile.txt", std::ios::app);   
      
    cout << "\nEnter something to write in file : " << endl;
    
    std::string line;
    getline(cin, line);

    out_file2 << line;  // writes to out_file2

    /* Reading from file again - */

    std::ifstream in_file2("outfile.txt"); // will open outfile.txt for reading.
    
    if( !in_file2 ) {
        std::cerr << "File didn't open. Error encountered." << endl;
    }

    char ch;

    cout << endl;

    while( in_file2.get(ch) ) {
        cout << ch;
    }
    
    /*
    Output (unexpected? why?)-
        100                                                                             
        456.78                                                                                          
        atik                                
    */

    in_file.close();
    in_file.close();
    out_file.close();
    out_file2.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Now, my `outfile..txt` is - (as expected):

```
100                                                                                             
456.78                                                                                         
atik                                                                                
Hello there
```

Then why is the output for `in_file2` not showing `Hello there`? Why does it truncate the `Hello there`? Can someone please explain?

Comment: Is this just one big program? In which case, you need to close (or at least flush) the ofstreams before any guarantee can be made about the writes making their way to the file.

Comment: at what line exactly do i have to flush the ofstream? and also it would be really helpful if you tell me  the best (syntax) way to do so. Thanks

Comment: Damn @frank thank you so much. because of you, i can sleep with peace today. My problem has been solved but my doubt remains. Why did we need to flush the stream after writing the line into out_file2 at all?

Comment: @LearningNoob123: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69621090/364696). The problem is user-mode buffers.

Comment: @LearningNoob123, because you are not writing to the file, you are sending data to an object tasked with writing to the file, and it does so when it pleases (or when you force it to).

Comment: Note that there is also kernel-mode buffering on most OSes (the `sync`/`fsync` calls are used to flush them), but it doesn't matter much outside of abrupt power loss scenarios, because as soon as the data reaches the kernel, it's visible to all processes that open the file "normally" (it's possible it won't be visible to processes that open the file with `O_DIRECT` to bypass the kernel caches, but that shouldn't be used regularly).

Answer (score 3):

```
out_file2<<line;
```

doesn't flush (the use of `std::endl` in the prior code does), so if there's less than a full block of data read from `std::cin`, the data written to `out_file2` is likely stuck in your user-mode buffers (and not visible when you open the file for read independently). Those buffers make I/O efficient by reducing the number of system calls when you're performing many smallish writes, in exchange for any buffered data not being visible outside of that file handle until the buffer is flushed (implicitly by filling, or explicitly by manual flushing or closing the file handle).

Simply changing that line to:

```
out_file2 << line << std::flush;
```

(or just `.close()`ing `out_file2` once you're done with it) will cause it to flush properly and you should see the new data on opening it again for read.

Comment: Alternatively: Use scopes to let RAII take care of the cleanup

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you so much. it solved my problem but could you please elaborate why we need to flush the buffer after writing in out_file2 but not in out_file? i kind of got that you wrote in brackets but still confused since english is not my first language, so a little elaboration would be highly appreciated. Anyway, Thanks for your time sir.

Comment: @Frank: Yes, implicit `close`ing via adding extra curly braces around the segment of the code declaring/using `out_file2` is also reasonable.

Comment: @LearningNoob123: User-mode buffering is a thing for basically all programming languages. If the overhead of a system call is (made up numbers) 500 ns (to signal kernel to write data from user process), but only 1 ns per byte to copy between arrays, if you don't use user-mode buffering, outputting a byte at a time would cost 501 ns per byte, or over 2 ms to write 4096 bytes; half a second to write 1 MB). If you instead buffer 4096 bytes, then perform one system call for all of them, the cost is 4096 (for writes to user buffer) + 500 + 4096 ns ~= 8.7 μs (less than one 250th of the cost).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Wow! Got alot to learn from you today. Thanks a ton buddy :)